# Android: Getting phone owner info

Tags: android

Since there is the permission called

```
android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA
```

there MUST be a way to read the phone owner info on an android device.

The only thing I could find on the net is this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, "owner");
Cursor c = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

But 1) that doesn't work (owner path unknown) and 2) Contacts.People is deprecated (I guess this should now be ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)

I can't even get the mobile phone number of the device using the TelephonyManager (getLine1Number) ... even the built-in phoneinfo screen shows "unknown" for the phonenumber.

Anyway, seems like I can't figure it out on my own and can't find anything useful on the web either (except for the outdated (?) code above). Although I believe the above approach must be the right one (using some content provider that provides the owner info). There simply is no documentation about this except that Android provides the permission setting "android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" but no info about how to actually do that kind of thing.

Does anybody know how to get to the phone owner info (name, address, email, phone, ...) on Android? Thanks a mill!

(Background: Developing on Android SDK 2.1, Testing on Emulator and HTC Desire)

Comment: Have you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Android is open source.  It seems, based on searching for `READ_OWNER_DATA`, that the "`/people/owner`" path in the `contacts` provider returns a cursor with some sort of owner information — assuming that information has been entered already by the user.

You'd have to double check the AOSP to see if that still applies for the newer contacts API.

Answer (score -1):

this permission was removed 
see :
http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes/android.Manifest.permission.html

Comment: The permission the OP was using is gone and that's unfortunate. Perhaps you could expand on another way to do it?